# preg_replace with UTF-8 letter

Tags: regex, preg-replace

i need allowed in name only letter and number, but letters must be UTF-8, because which will be used in German, Spanish and other languages

My code throws UTF-8 characters, how fix it?
Thanks

```
$title = 'aj,o!_-z5ąśäżźŠń?56';

echo preg_replace('/[^A-z0-9-]/', '_', $title);
```

Answer (score 4):

First,

**`[A-z]` is an error.  Never use the range `A-z` in a character class.**

It matches the same characters as `[A-Za-z]`, *plus* several special characters whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.  If you really wanted to match just the ASCII letters, you would use `[A-Za-z]`, or `[A-Z]` with the "case-insensitive" flag set.

As for your question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\d-]/u', '_', $title);
```

The `/u` flag tells it to treat the regex and the source string as UTF-8, and it allows you to use Unicode properties like `\p{L}` in the regex.  `\d` is just a more compact way to match `[0-9]` (ASCII decimal digits).  Depending on your needs, you might want to use `\p{N}` (Unicode numbers) or `\p{Nd}` (Unicode decimal digits) instead, but I'm pretty sure `\d` will suffice.